# Showing that the complete flag variety is rational

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, manifolds

I want to show that the set of complete flags in $F^n$ is a rational algebraic variety, i.e. it is a manifold where the transition maps are ratios of polynomials. The atlas I can come up with is $\{\pi_P: PU^- \to Fl_n(F)\}$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix and $U^-$ is the unipotent subgroup. $\pi_P$ simply takes $F^i$ to be the span of the left $i$ columns, that way I get a flag $\{0\} = F^0 \subset F^1 \subset F^2 \subset \dots \subset F^{n-1} \subset F^n$ out of the $n$ columns of a element of $PU^-$. Since any square matrix admits $PLU$ factorizations, the images of $\pi_P$ cover $Fl_n(F)$.

However, I just don't quite see how this operation can be thought of as a homeomorphism. But suppose it is, then I need to define what it means for a subset $U \subseteq Fl_n(F)$ to be open. $PU^-$ is an affine subspace of dimension $n\choose{2}$, if I can write what $\pi_P$ does analytically as polynomials, then I should be able to use the fact that any level set of a polynomial with coefficients in $F$ is closed to define openness in $Fl_n(F)$, but I have not thought it through.

But suppose I have done that, then I think I have shown that the set of complete flags is an analytic manifold. To further show that it is a rational algebraic variety, I need to show that the transition maps are ratios of polynomials. To do this, I think I will need to find some special subset of $PU^-$ such that it is the intersection of two sources of the charts. Then I should be able to write the transition map $\pi_Q^{-1} \circ \pi_P$ that maps one intersection to another in terms of ratios of polynomials, where the ratios come from inverting matrices. But I just cannot how exactly I can do this. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!